# Import (HTML, CSS, JS) Component into index.html

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, module

I am using webpack with a modular / component architecture.

My end result is a webpage that uses several previously made components (consisting of HTML, CSS, JS) that I wanted to slot into my index.html.

I was hoping to use webpack for that, just like we do with web-apps. I do not want to write all the HTML logic into the JS files, in the components. But, I am not sure how to get the HTML files in each component to bundle with the JS and CSS in that same component, and thus automatically bundle all of it into the main index.html.

Any idea? I am struggling to see how the component's HTML bundles into the main index.html.

**The structure I had in mind was a typical web app structure:**

```
- src/
  - assets/
  - components/
    - compOne/
      - compOne.html
      - compOne.css
      - compOne.scss
    - compTwo/
      - compTwo.html
      - compTwo.css
      - compTwo.scss
  - index.html
  - styles.scss
  - index.js
- dist/
```

Comment: Which framework are you using or you just build the component with VanillaJS? Building a component without framework is not too easy, you can check this blog: https://codeburst.io/little-todo-javascript-html-components-without-frameworks-87914d6dd2e. For scss and css, you will need to install 'sass-loader' and 'css-loader' in your webpack so they can be imported into your es6 components.

Comment: Hi @MattYao. I have a full webpack setup that is working, with all the typical loaders etc.. I usually use that for bigger projects, so I know it works well. In this case, I am just trying to build a website in a modular fashion. Without any framework. I just want to say insert pre-bundled HTML/CSS/JS components here and there on the site. Many components used in making websites, can be reused, and it would be easier if we could do it automatically with webpack or similar.

Comment: Too bad Gulp has fallen out of favor. It is especially adept at doing this type of thing. You code it, it does precisely what you ask. The html-inject plug in is a great example of this. You define a custom label to go into your static HTML files and tell gulp/html-inject to load specific files in place of that placeholder at build time. You have to write custom loader to do it, but it is quite simple.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Perhaps my JavaScript component module could export the DOM of its corresponding HTML component. That way I could easily import it into a new site, and just set innerHtml of any element that should use the component, to whatever the JS bundle exported. So: 1) Modular HTML/CSS/JS components should be placed in the hierarchy as seen in OP. Each JS should import its CSS and export the <body> node of its HTML file. 2) main.js imports the bundle(s) and inserts it into index.html with innerHtml. Thoughts?

Comment: What module format are you using in your JS source files?